# Using BreezeJs on NodeJs with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, node.js, breeze

I have a rather central module that performs deep copies and cascading deletes on BreezeJs object graphs. I want to move some of these operations server-side, but I'm not looking forward to maintaining separate JavaScript and C# versions of this code.

From what I can tell, BreezeJs can be used as an ORM/ORD for MongoDB on NodeJs, but can it be used on NodeJs directly connected to SQL Server so that I can reuse my JavaScript code?

The only other way I can envisage this is by having my NodeJs instance make requests to the /breeze/ endpoint on my ASP.NET Web API server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [breeze-sequelize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/breeze-sequelize) npm package lets you use Breeze with the [Sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/) ORM, which supports MSSQL.

The [docs for breeze-sequelize](http://breeze.github.io/doc-node-sequelize/class-descriptions.html) are a bit thin, but there are a [couple of samples](http://breeze.github.io/doc-samples/) that use it.